# cakephp 2.4 upload an image

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i'm trying to upload an image and make a thumbnail of this image by using this [Behavior (github)](https://github.com/cakecoded/image-upload-behavior) [tutorial](http://www.cakecoded.com/article/cakephp-image-upload-behavior-with-php-thumb)

I'm using the blog tutorial on [cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html) website.

I'm getting this following errors each time I want to upload the images. I'm dowloading an .jpeg file

```
Invalid file type. Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif allowed.
```

My Model/Post.php

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {
        public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );

public $actsAs = array('ImageUpload' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'required'               => false,
            'directory'           => 'img/uploads/',
            'allowed_mime'        => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'),
            'allowed_extension'   => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'),
            'allowed_size'        => 2097152,
            'random_filename'     => true,
            'resize' => array(
                'thumb' => array(
                    'directory' => 'img/uploads/thumbs/',
                    'phpThumb' => array(
                        'far' => 1,
                        'bg'  => 'FFFFFF',
                        'zc' => 0
                    ),
                    'width' => 230,
                    'height' => 150
                ),
                'max' => array(
                    'directory' => 'img/uploads/thumbs/',
                    'phpThumb' => array(
                        //'far' => 1,
                        //'bg'  => 'FFFFFF',
                        'zc' => 0
                    ),
                    'width' => 400,
                    'height' => 300
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

}
```

Comment: what is the file's name you are trying to upload?

Comment: Hi this is my file name 1094969_770375626323369_2132578277_n.jpg

Comment: may be the problem is file size,'allowed_mime'or'allowed_extension'. first check with one extension and single mime type without resize and chek . may be the issue is in resize .